# Get file from server with local application

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload

I am working on a project that allow user to apply on X jobs online. The project I am working on is in ASP.net. What I wanna do is to save the CV of all users to the server. I have no problem to achieve this step. The problem I have is, I don't know how I can make this file accessible for my internal application. I did a lot of research, and I didn't find a way to do this.

**What I am try to do :**

1. User will go on the web application to apply on jobs, then I save their CV on the server.
2. Each day, I want to do a request to the server with my local application (I am coding with c#.net)
3. If their is new CV in the server file, I want to take the files and copy it to the local server.

**Important :**

1. One server is online (web server)
2. The web server have security
3. The other server is local

**Conclusion**

I am asking your help, I had no luck with my research to find the "best" and "easiest" way to upload the server files to the local server. So please can you tell me a way to achieve this. I am not asking you to find the "Perfect solution", I just want some tips.

This is what I found :

1. [Mobile Acess](http://www.egnyte.com/file-server/mobile-access.html)
2. [Browser Stack](http://www.browserstack.com/local-testing)

I am not sure if I should use a third-party app to do this, or if I should create my own method.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Suggestion: Based on the volume of files saved in the server file system, you may choose to save files in DB. which is easier to maintain and high scale ability.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am already planning to save the path in the db that I am using for the web application.

Comment: My suggestion was to save the file to DB in binary column, instead of saving in server's file system. (eg. oracle BLOB). Since you are planning to save path in DB, add another column to store file created/uploaded time stamp. based on this timestamp column you may write a simple query to select files uploaded yesterday or any range of days/date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if the two servers are disconnected as you say then you'll need to expose a web service on the web server that you can contact. This web service, with a little bit of knowledge, could easily provide you the header information (e.g. file names) for the new files, and then also provide an endpoint to download each of those files one at a time.

I **would not recommend** simply exposing the folder the files are in and allowing consumers to list and read its contents. Make sure they have to authenticate through the web service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the server are not on the same network, one is in the cloud(web) the other is local. I edited my questions to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok ! yes yes, I see your point, I already have a webservice, so what I can do is call this web service, then I return the filename, and the path of the file, so i can mannually find the file and copy it. Am i right ? If yes, the problem that I see concern the security... ?

Comment: @VincP.: the path to the file won't do you any good. You need to actually call an entry point that will set the `Reponse` to the `byte[]` of the actual file. You need to **literally** download the file like the browser would.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! My point is, I need to link a demand to a CV, to create this link, I actually need the path of the CV. If I want to know which CV is who.

Comment: @VincP., that actually depends on how your service is setup. If it's a `REST`ful service then you'd have a path to that entity (e.g. `/cvs/1490202`) -but if it's a basic `SOAP` service then you'd just have an endpoint to call.